# its possible, and how if yes, create exceptions for ValidateAdminCodeSignatures registry value enabled?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, security-policy

modifying the `ValidateAdminCodeSignatures` value contained in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` Windows enforce PKI signature checks on any interactive application that requests elevation of privilege; and I think its good, but I want continue to use some software (trusted by me) but blocked by this registry value (if enabled), only some exceptions in combo with this value enabled.

its possible to create exception for this value, and if yes, how?

Comment: FWIW, I see you have engaged with others in the same way on other SE sites [as shown here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/30954/can-an-object-a-person-ingests-enter-the-appendix?newreg=e9599aee103849229b7b0da23177d2bd#comment59492_30954): At the end of the day you are alienating others who are here to help you. Nobody changed the core of your text or anything else. Simply capitalizing is part of basic grammar. And if you don’t capitalize, others will look at your question as being grammatically incorrect and might judge it as such.

Comment: [@Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/users/167207/giacomo1968) You dont have help me in any way, the others who answered me understood how I write without difficulty, and they did not complain, here you are only complaining, and I repeat: *I am not here to discuss this*

Comment: Tovot, we're trying to be helpful and good to you improving your question in small but important ways. There is no benefit to you to roll those changes back. There is a lot of benefit to you to leave them be.

Comment: @music2myear Agreed. But please also note how TOVOT is directly linking to user profiles in replies. That seems odd and excessively manual. So copy edits are not useful but direct linking to user profiles is? These interactions make little sense.

Comment: @TOVOT Went to [your website](https://arbitrio.altervista.org/archive/writing/2019/scrivere-bene/) — as linked to in [your bio](https://superuser.com/users/1482904/tovot) — and found [this page](https://arbitrio.altervista.org/archive/writing/2019/scrivere-bene/) whose English title is “Way of Writing” in which you state: “• alphabetical symbols are called symbols, not letters; letters are those that are send • I write the first symbol of pronouns and nouns with the first capital symbol • I write the abbreviations without the abbreviation points and all the symbols in capital letters” (1/2)

Comment: You then say, “in this way what you write is cleaner and more organized. writing at every beginning sentence with capital letters is confusion, capitalization should only be used for names and pronouns (and anything that indicates a specific element in a generic context), to distinguish them from other words. while I am writing, even committing myself, I managed to write well (so), only in this site created by me.” While I don’t understand your ideas, it might be worth it to add this to your bio. I’m clearly not the only one who notices this non-standard grammar. Be clear on these sites. (2/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy solution here: [GitHub ─ bypassUAC](https://github.com/genome21/bypassUAC)

the commandis simple, just need Command Prompt:

`cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" "`*~\path\executable.exe*`""`

Answer (score 3):

If the requirement is only that the .exe must be signed, you can sign the software yourself:

1. Create a code-signing certificate, e.g. using PowerShell's `New-SelfSignedCertificate` or other tools. (It's almost like a TLS certificate except with a different extendedKeyUsage.)

   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows
   - https://sectigostore.com/page/how-do-i-generate-a-self-signed-code-signing-certificate/
   - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing
2. Export the certificate (without private key) to a .crt file and import it back to the "Trusted Publishers" section.
3. Use `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` (or signtool.exe if you have it) to sign each .exe that you want to allow.

(You might want to do this from another computer than the protected one. Alternatively you could store the certificate's private key in the TPM or a Yubikey, where it'd have PIN protection.)

Comment: [@Utente1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686) interesting, something I wonder, since I see that you are well versed in the topic, ValidateAdminCodeSignatures actually adds an real extra layer of security, or is it easily bypassable from prompt way or scripts, even inside or outside the system?